# Filtering related entities for a list of values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, eager-loading

I have the following entity classes in my application:

```
public class Project
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProjectManager> ProjectManagers { get; set; }
}

public class Manager
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectManager
{
    public virtual int ManagerId { get; set; }
    public virtual int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual bool CanUpdate { get; set; }
    public virtual bool CanDelete { get; set; }
}
```

I am loading the list of projects for current manager:

```
var projects = context.Projects.Where(
    x => x.ProjectManagers.Any(y => y.ManagerId == currentManagerId)
);
```

The `ProjectManagers` property for each project now contains information aboult *all* managers, but I want to only load the *current* manager's record.

I have seen the following approach:

```
context.Entry(project)
       .Collection(x => x.ProjectManagers)
       .Query()
       .Where(x => x.ManagerId == currentManagerId)
       .Load();
```

However, it requires a separate `SELECT` query for each of the projects. Can it be done in a single query for the entire list of projects?

To clarify:

```
// Sample of an existing data
var existing = new []
{
    new Project
    {
        Name = "A",
        ProjectManagers =
        {
            new ProjectManager { ManagerId = 1 },
            new ProjectManager { ManagerId = 2 },
            new ProjectManager { ManagerId = 3 }
        }
    },
    new Project
    {
        Name = "B",
        ProjectManagers =
        {
            new ProjectManager { ManagerId = 2 },
        }
    },
};

// What I want to get (in a single query!)
var desired = new []
{
    new Project
    {
        Name = "A",
        ProjectManagers =
        {
            new ProjectManager { ManagerId = 1 },
            // nobody else here
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: is this because of lazyloading?

Comment: So the project A from the `desired` list, as an object is different project from the A from the `existing` list, as it has different managers? You might set yourself for failure later...

Comment: @SWeko, not really, because EF knows that only some related entities are loaded. It works like a charm with one single project, I just need a way to apply the same logic to a list of project.

Comment: AFAIK, EF knows only if a related property was loaded or not - I don't know that it can handle this kind of semi-loaded scenarios gracefully.
E.g. what should happen if you add a second manager to the `desired` project, and save changes on it?

Comment: @SWeko, the data just goes through RIA WCF to the client and I'm only displaying it, not saving anything. Shouldn't be a major problem.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!